# Почему sql запрос удаляет все дубликаты

Tags: sql, postgresql

Допустим есть таблица с столбцом val у которой три записи 1,1,1.  Я хочу удалить дубликаты и оставить одну запись 1. Но мой запрос удаляет все. Почему?

```
delete from test t1 where val = ( select val from test t2 where t1.val = t2.val group by val having count(val) > 1 )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172683/10138734

Answer (score 2):

Удаление происходит, так как в подзапрос попадают *все* строки с данным значением `val`.

Если есть какое-то дополнительное поле, по которому можно различать разные записи, например таймстемп создания записи `created_at`, можно найти соответствующее минимальное значение и удалять всё что больше этого таймстемпа, используя `DELETE USING`

```sql
DELETE FROM test t1
USING (
    SELECT val, MIN(created_at) mntime
    FROM test t2
    GROUP BY val
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) d
WHERE t1.val = d.val AND t1.created_at > d.mntime;
```

Если такого отдельного поля нет, можно аналогично использовать встроенный идентификатор записи `ctid`:

```sql
DELETE FROM test t1
USING (
    SELECT val, MIN(ctid) mnid
    FROM test t2
    GROUP BY val
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) d
WHERE t1.val = d.val AND t1.ctid > d.mnid;
```

---

Решение из [PostgresQL Wiki: Deleting Duplicates](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates) использует оконную функцию и предполагает, что есть некое ключевое поле `id` -- идентификатор записи:

```sql
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY id) as rnum
        FROM test
    ) t
    WHERE t.rnum > 1
);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотел бы уточнить в чем я неправ. Как я понимаю подзапрос выполняться для каждого значения val. Соответственно если у нас в таблице  (1,1,1)  то после первого подзапроса станет (1,1) , после второго (1) а третий вернет null так как у нас есть условие при группировки "group by val having count(val) > 1 ".  Соответственно в таблице у нас останется (1). В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: @Alex031, нет, запрос сначала найдёт все записи, и только после этого начнёт удалять. Чтоб сработало как вы хотите нужно бежать по таблице курсором, и для каждой отдельной записи выполнять проверку и удаление. А DELETE (как и UPDATE) обрабатывает не по одной записи, а все за раз.

Answer (score 0):

Если описать в общих чертах, что `DELETE` выполняется в два этапа:

1. Выполняется `SELECT` с аналогичным условием `WHERE`, который готовит список записей.
2. Выполняется собственно удаление по ранее подготовленному списке.

Могу ошибаться, но, вроде бы, это требование стандарта SQL.

Если бы это делалось не так, то появлялись бы побочные эффекты, в частности ваш запрос в мог оставить любую из 3-х записей, и при каждом запуске разную. В некоторых устаревших СУБД можно встретить ожидаемое вами поведение, и в них есть костыль в виде предложения `ORDER BY` у `DELETE`